# Jslider can not tick when its value changed from JButton periodically

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, swingworker, jslider

I am working on a `swing` project. There is a map, I have raster images of a given data for different times. Normally I change the time via a `JSlider` and it requests server for raster image. Then I add response image to map. There is a Play `JButton`, when pressed it will add those images one by one to raster layer of the map. It will be seen as an animation. In that `JButton's` `actionPerfomed` method I change the `JSlider's` value in a for loop.

My problem is when I press Play `JButton`, I can't see the data is played but I know code block works because I record each image(from server). I found out that it is becuse of `JButton` does not release `Focus` until its `actionPerformed` method ends. Because `JButton` looked like it was pressed until the end. So I only see the last image in the map.

First, I tried `JButton.setFocusable(false)` etc. but to no good.

Second, I tried using `SwingWorker`. I added it like this:

```
class PlayMvgmLayerWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

public PlayMvgmLayerWorker(String title) {
    super(title);
}

@Override
protected void done(Void aVoid) {

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() {
    try{
        BufferedImage[] image = new BufferedImage[24];
        for(int i=0; i<24; i++) {

            final int value = i - 48 + 24;
            timeSlider.setValue( value );
            Thread.sleep(10000l);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

---

```
private JButton animation = new JButton("");

animation.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        new PlayMvgmLayerWorker("title").execute();
    }
});
```

---

```
private JSlider timeSlider = new JSlider();
timeSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // time consuming processes ( server call, add image to map, etc)
    }
});
```

I tried to simplify it.

It is much better than before, but I still can not see the data played properly.  Sometimes data is played after `JSlider` ticks. Could it be because my time consuming process is in the `second components(JSlider)` `stateChanged` event? Should I use a second `SwingWorker` in `JSlider's` event too? Any suggestions about what can I do?

Moreover, what would be the best way to disable all components before playing data, and enable them after playing data?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have two activities Activity A and Activity B which have to be run simultaneously, you need to create a thread for the second activity - the first activity will already be run in its own thread (the main program).

The scheme is as follows:

```
Program A:

  create new Thread: Activity B

  run allother tasks for Activity A
```

In more specific terms the following program will run your simulation and update the tick of the slider:

```
public P() {

animation.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      doInBackgroundImp();
    }
});

  setSize(500, 500);
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  add(animation);
  add(timeSlider);
  setVisible(true);
}

protected void doInBackgroundImp() {
    Thread th=new Thread() {
      public void run() {
    try{
        for(int i=0; i<24; i++) {

            final int value = i - 48 + 24;
            timeSlider.setValue( i );
            System.out.println(timeSlider.getValue()+" "+value);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
      }
    };
    th.start();
}

private JButton animation = new JButton("");

private JSlider timeSlider = new JSlider();

}
```